# Analytic Map from $B(0,1)$ to $B(0,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Is the analytic map from $B(0,1)$ to $B(0,1)$ such that  $f(0)=1/2$ and $f'(0)=3/4$ unique?

Comment: Do you know Schwarz' lemma? And if you do, have you an idea how you may use it here? (The answer, by the way, is yes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, normalize the self-maps of $B(0,1)$ so that $0$ goes to $0$.

Namely, let $$g(z) = \frac{f(z)-1/2}{1-\frac12 f(z)}$$
which is $f$ composed with a Möbius transformation $\phi(z) = \frac{z-1/2}{1-z/2}$. Using the chain rule, calculate 
$$g'(0) = \phi'(1/2)f'(0) = \frac{4}{3}\frac{3}{4} =1$$
The (equality case of) Schwarz lemma does the rest.